# TagLib Qt project linking issue

Tags: c++, mingw, qt-creator, taglib

I am builded TagLib 1.11.1 library with cmake for MinGW, installed it and connected to my Qt project:

```
INCLUDEPATH += \
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/taglib/include/taglib" \

LIBS += \
    -L"C:/Program Files (x86)/taglib/lib" -llibtag
```

But after running my program i get following errors:

```
In function `Z5qMainiPPc':
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib8FileNameC1EPKw'
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib7FileRefC1ENS_8FileNameEbNS_15AudioProperties9ReadStyleE'
undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6TagLib7FileRefD1Ev'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't understand, what i'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The `-l` flag implies you should leave the `lib` and the `.a` or  `.dll.a` part out if the library name, so the linker flag should be `-ltag`.

Also, it looks like you're doing a shared build, so you will need the shared build of taglib (which includes the DLL file and libtag.dll.a).

You can build the shared version of taglib by adding the CMake flag `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON`.

Comment: Please update your post with the steps you did and their results.